# Python: Avoiding for-loop in combination with range

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I got an input function to choose products out of an entered input number of products with some error handling. For this, I used a `for` loop in combination with `range`, which is not very pythonic, as it should be possible to iterate over without using range, but unfortunately, I didn't manage. So this is (part of my) code:

```
valid_expression = False # for next while loop
    while valid_expression is False:
        products = []

        for i in range(no_of_products_sel):
            products_confirmed = False # for next while loop
            while products_confirmed is False:
                product = input(f"Please enter product name {i+1}:")
                if product.lower().strip() == "exit":
                    print("See you soon!")
                    return None
                product_clean = product.lower().title().strip()
                if product_clean in products:
                    print(f"Already chosen! Choose another product!")

                elif product_clean in list_of_products:
                    products.append(product_clean)
                    products_codes[product_clean]=product_codes(product)  # get product codes, save them in dict
                    product_confirmed = True

                elif product_clean not in list_of_products:
                    print(f"\n---\nYou have entered '{product}', which is not in the stock. Enter another product!\n---\n")

            valid_expression = True
```

How can I avoid the combination of for-loop and range in `for i in range(no_of_products_sel):`?

Comment: seems fine to me... as you do not yet have a list to iterate over, but you do have the number of iterations, this seems fine to me. what i am more concerned about is the `valid_expression` while loop, that only ever executes once.